# How can i select 'Entity' and 'RBC' like the output?

Tags: python, data-science

How can i get this output from this dataframe?
(what is the min['Close'] for each bank's stock throughout the time?)
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5B3n.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrQKz.png).imgur.com/QRnUi.png

Answer (score 0):

According to the data set, Open, High ,low, Close and Volume are like the sub headings under RBC, CIBC, ...etc

The out put of the data set entirely depends upon the model that has been implemented.